# trying to find if title contains word then hide that parent element

Tags: javascript, jquery, search, for-loop

```
    var search_input = $('#input_search');
    var search_console = search_input.val();
    var header_console = $('.header');
    $('#enter_console').click(function() {
        var bodies = $('.reviews');
        for(var i=0;i<bodies.length;i++){
            var bodies = bodies[i];
            if($(bodies).find(header_console).filter(':contains("+search_console+")')) {
                bodies[i].hide();
            }
        }
    });
```

I am trying to find if the bodies has the word that a user types in in the input. Then if that bodies has the word hide the rest of the elements except it. Can anyone help me??? Basic html looks like

```
<div id="2343" class="reviews">
    <h2>Animal Crossing: City Folk</h2><h3 class="header">Wii</h3>
    <p>8/10</p>
    <img src="http://i1231.photobucket.com/albums/ee512/Rukiafan23/1_zpsdab192dc.jpg" alt="{title}"> 
    <a href="http://www.wiiwarewave.com/t93-animal-crossing-city-folk">
        Read this Review
    </a>
    <div class="inner_box_review">----</div>
</div>
```

Comment: If you hide the "bodies", you will hide the title as well since it is a child of .reviews.  You may need to rewrite your HTML to accomplish this.

Comment: What should happen if the word is simply a letter, such as `a`? Presumably more than one element will have that 'word'?

Comment: yeah which all those elements should be hidden.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should do it:

```
$('#enter_console').click(function() {
    var search_input = $('#input_search'),
        search_console = search_input.val(),
        header_console = $('.header');
    $('.reviews:has(.header:contains("' + search_console + '"))').hide();
});
```

fixed a quote issue as well.

the selector says: "Select all elements with class "reviews" that have at least one descendant that contains the text stored within `search_console`."

If you need to do the opposite and hide all that DONT have said text, you need `.not(` or `:not()`

```
$('#enter_console').click(function() {
    var search_input = $('#input_search'),
        search_console = search_input.val(),
        header_console = $('.header');
    $('.reviews').not(':has(.header:contains("' + search_console + '"))').hide();
});
```

or

```
$('#enter_console').click(function() {
    var search_input = $('#input_search'),
        search_console = search_input.val(),
        header_console = $('.header');
    $('.reviews:not(:has(.header:contains("' + search_console + '")))').hide();
});
```

Comment: This doesn't work at all. also I don't want the element that contains the word to be hidden, I want the other elements to be hidden.

Comment: wouldn't I have to do an if statement with a ! in front of it? like 
`if(!element) { //code here  }` then it would be var element = `$('.reviews').children('.header:has(:contains("'+search_console+'"))');`

Comment: You want to hide all children of the .review div other than the one that contains the text? or do you want to hide all .review divs that DONT contain said text. And no, you don't need an if statement.

Comment: All .review divs that Don't contain the said text in the class .header in it

Comment: I added the specification of .header, maybe that'll make it a little more efficient. I also added the reverse as requested.

Comment: Ok still not working for some reason here is a jsbin. http://jsbin.com/ekajeb/1/edit  I am using a JavaScript template. the Javascript for this is all the way at the bottom ok.

Comment: @EasyBB You are never updating the value of search_console. See updated

Comment: AHHH so the variables were what was messing it all up after all thank you.

Comment: Thank it works perfectly. Is there any way to make it specific? As there is WiiWave Wii Ware and some other stuff. anyway to be specific, if not it is ok because it works for the most part

Comment: You could, but you would have to do the :not(:has(:contains( part in .filter manually instead. Your original code would probably be easier to modify toward that goal

Comment: ok so like  $('.reviews').not(':has(".header").filter(:contains("' + search_console + '"))').hide();

Comment: No, more like `$('.reviews').filter(function(){ return $('.header',this).text() != search_console;}).hide();`

Comment: Ah ok. I see now that does look better lol. Thank you for your help, greatly appreciated! I'd upvote and check it 5 times if I could :D